# Forçar retorno error no ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Por exemplo ao inserir o cliente (no PHP) validar se idade é acima de 18, antes de inserir, valida com um condição, e caso entrar retornar um erro, que no ajax, podia fazer tipo:

```
 success: function (data) {
      alert('Sucesso');
 },
 error: function (data) {
      alert('Ocorreu um erro, verifique a idade informada!');
 }
```

Comment: O erro do ajax é para erros na ligação, e não para "estado". Envia no PH uma variável via `data` dessa callback `success` e consoante esse data alertas o conteúdo correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `sucess` do ajax é para casos em que o ajax completou sua execução corretamente, mandando/recebendo dados do servidor e o `error` é ativado quando ocorre algum problema HTTP(exemplo, erro 500).

Caso você queira fazer uma validação de idade você pode retornar um json no backend com "error": "mensagem do erro" ou em caso de sucesso "sucesso": "mensagem de sucesso", daí você realizaria a verificação no front pelo parâmetro `sucess` do ajax.